# Kubuntu 11.04 Japanese input method

Tags: kubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, ime

I've tried using iBus as a Japanese input method. I installed it from the repositories, as well as ibus-anthy, and it's sometimes functional, but not on Firefox or Thunderbird, which is where I need it most...

I tried removing it and installing SCIM, but I can't get it to work at all. I might just be botching up the configuration, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it. In the end, I used IBus. Before, I was trying to run `ibus-setup` which would start the IBus daemon, but it appears that the daemon wouldn't have the correct permissions to be able to set up triggers everywhere, or something to that effect.

Under KDE 4.6, I went to System Settings -> Locale -> System Languages -> System Default, and selected my default language (English), and set the keyboard input method to `ibus`. Then, a quick restart ran the daemon on startup and it worked fine.